# jQuery, as user scrolls, give element a CSS value matching distance scrolled

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a layout that I'm working on that requires the sidebar to become fixed after a certain distance has been scrolled.

This works fine except when the user scrolls to the very bottom of the page and my site's footer starts overlapping the sidebar.

What I want to be able to do is, once a user has scrolled down the page and reached the top of the footer (Determined using jQuery `.offset`) the sidebar will take on CSS `transform:translateY(-XX)` values where the `-XX` represents the distance the user has scrolled since reaching the top of the footer.

So for example, my footer is 190px in height, so if a user has scrolled to the very foot of the page, my sidebar will have a CSS property of `transform:translateY(-190px)`. If they've only scrolled 20px into the footer then the value will be `transform:translateY(-20px)`

Here is the code I'm working with right now;

```
// ==========================================================================
// Sticky ad
// ==========================================================================

var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var adFixer = jQuery('.sidebar');
var adOffset = adFixer.offset();
var adHeight = jQuery('.ad-widget').height();
var scrollOffset = adHeight + 70;
var scrollInnerHeight = windowHeight - scrollOffset;

var footerOffset = $('#footer').offset();

var $document = jQuery(document),
className = 'fixed';

// Only run sticky ad if ad is less than 2/3 of the height
// of the browser window

if ( adHeight < (windowHeight * 0.66) ) {

    $document.scroll(function() {
      if ($document.scrollTop() >= adOffset.top - 70) {

        jQuery('.sidebar').addClass(className);
        jQuery('.sidebar-scrollable').css({ 'top' : scrollOffset });
        jQuery('.scrollable-inner').css({ 'height' : scrollInnerHeight });

      } else if ($document.scrollTop() >= footerOffset.top) {

        // User has scrolled to the top of the footer
        // start applying negative transform:translateY() value to sidebar
        // based on how far user has scrolled into footer

      } else {

        jQuery('.sidebar').removeClass(className);
        jQuery('.sidebar-scrollable').css({ 'top' : 'auto' });
        jQuery('.scrollable-inner').css({ 'height' : 'auto' });

      }
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example?

Comment: @JohnBupit I've added the code I'm working with right now

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. You can use [https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) for this. It has a limit option that stops the fixed position scrolling when the user hits a certian point. This limit can be any fixed number or position of an element on the page